# Any alternative term for "conspiracy theory" that doesn't imply it's paranoid/implausible?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Conspiracy theory" is generally taken to mean something like like "A paranoid theory about an implausible conspiracy".

But there are obviously legitimate theories about cover-ups etc, things that get investigated by legitimate government agencies (and sometimes found out to be true). Is there any neutral term for these kind of theories that doesn't carry connotations of wacky stuff like the fake Moon landing?

Comment: Have you looked up any synonyms?  What did you find that doesn't help you?  Please see the guidance on [single word requests] and provide a sample sentence showing how the word works in it.

Comment: What's wrong with the word you yourself are using, *theory*? Failing that, have you checked its synonyms?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where and how you would use it? If someone uncovers a fact you would state it as a fact not call it a theory, e.g. "He presented evidence the CIA were involved in the coup against Allende." vs "He had a conspiracy theory about the CIA..." Or do you want a word for a (real) conspiracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would "conjecture" fit the bill?

It's my conjecture, that gluten was introduced in the 70s marketed food as a higher concentration than natural to increase margins by gross weight.

The definition is (Merriam Webster) :

> 1: inference formed without proof or sufficient evidence.

This matches your case. It's deduced using a verifiable train of logic, but there isn't sufficient experimental evidence.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjecture

Answer (score 0):

You could call such positions **heterodox,** [defined in the modern sense by Cambridge as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/heterodox)

> (of beliefs, ideas, or activities) different from and opposing generally accepted beliefs or standards

Comment: I agree that is a bit more neutral in tone (doesn't imply 'paranoid') but I would say it still implies 'implausible'.

Answer (score 0):

**dissenting view**

**dissent**

Both denote views that aren't in keeping with those posing as mainstream.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dissenting-view